# How to resolve the webrtcvad.Error: Error while processing frame?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import glob
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy
import librosa
import webrtcvad

def get_vector(sig,rate):
    vec=np.empty((1,3))
    start=0
    end=320

    while(sig.shape[0]>=end+160):
        vad = webrtcvad.Vad()
        vad.set_mode(2)

        res=vad.is_speech(sig[start:end].tobytes(),rate) #speech_probability
        zero_crosses = np.nonzero(np.diff(sig[start:end]>0))[0].shape[0]/0.02 # zero crosses
        f=scipy.fft(sig[start:end])
        f0=min(np.absolute(f))                                         # f0 frequency

        start=start+160
        end=end+160

        vec=np.vstack((vec,np.array([res,zero_crosses,f0],ndmin=2)))

    mfcc_feat=librosa.feature.mfcc(sig,rate,numcep=12,winlen=0.020)[0:vec.shape[0],:]  # mfcc 
    fbank=librosa.feature.melspectrogram(sig,rate,nfilt=5)[0:vec.shape[0],:] # log filterbank energies 
    mfcc_grad=np.gradient(mfcc_feat,axis=0)                            # mfcc first derivative

   final_feature=np.hstack((mfcc_feat,mfcc_grad,fbank,vec))

   return final_feature


df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1,6):
    for file in glob.glob("Actor_0102/*.wav".format(i)):
        print(file)
        (sig,rate,) = librosa.load(file)

    # get mfcc
        mfcc_feat = librosa.feature.mfcc(sig,rate)

    # get filterbank energies
        fbank_feat = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(sig,rate)


        final_vector=get_vector(sig,rate)
        feed_dict={"Features":final_vector.astype(np.float64),"name":file.split('/')[-1].split(',')[0]}
        df=df.append(feed_dict,ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv("Mfccfeatures.csv")
```

I am using RAVDESS data set and getting error:

> `webrtcvad.Error: Error while processing frame`

when I try to create features of multiple audio files and to store them in a CSV file

Comment: I've updated the formatting to make sure all of your code is understood to be just that (code).

Comment: yes this is the code

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error message and finally solved.
(I don't know whether your problem and mine are similar or not...)

Did you already check the sampling rate for the audio?
The webrtcvad says that
`The WebRTC VAD only accepts 16-bit mono PCM audio, sampled at 8000, 16000, 32000 or 48000 Hz`.
When I tried the rate of 48000 (originally 44100), it worked.